# Facebook integration using sharekit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

i did the integration with facebook using sharekit api .but every time it is taking the username and password i already entered in it .and it is opening directly sharing screen i need to open username and password screen and it has to be filled with username and password those are previously entered and show a option login as a different username.how to do that can any one share the code...this is my code... i am sharing the text..

// Create the item to share (in this example, a url)
   NSString *someText = @"ShareKit faceBook integration is the easiest amoung all the methods available in ios";
   SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:someText];

// Get the ShareKit action sheet
   SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

// Display the action sheet
   [actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];

Answer (score 2):

Logging Out / Removing Stored Logins

There are three methods to remove stored credentials:

// Remove credentials for all services

```
   [SHK logoutOfAll];
```

// Remove credentials for a specific service
// Use the service's class name: ex SHKTwitter, SHKDelicious

```
    [SHK logoutOfService:@"SHKReadItLater"];
```

// Remove credentials for a specific service (alternative method)
// call +logout on any sharer class

```
   [SHKTwitter logout];
```